# How to make this vector field animation

Tags: 2d, animation, vector

This screenshot is from Windows app called MyRadar by ACME AtronOmatic LLC. I found their wind direction animation to be very visually appealing and was wondering if anyone knew how to create this animation?

[image]

[image]

I prefer Java, Python, C++, or MATLAB answers for the code for creating this animation if possible.

Edit: So I know MATLAB and Python already have libraries for creating vector fields. However, I only found the ones that only change the direction and magnitude of the arrow. In this animation, the vector field arrow moves along the vector field.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I added the gif. Hope it gives you a better understanding of what animation I want.

Comment: Where does the problem lies, in fields generation or in rendering with existing fields?

Comment: In rendering existing fields.